# Can we integrate Pentaho Data Integration tool with .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, integration, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have Dot Net application, Now I want to integrate and call Pentaho Data Integration jobs with existing application asp.net c# is there any way to do this.

How I could integrate Pentaho with .NET looking for some tutorials or articles but here is nothing

Comment: Do you not want to integrate at the data level instead of the API level?

Comment: I want to achieve this by using  REST API but i have no idea how to start it